# Rename and then copy is not working

Tags: powershell

I am trying to rename certain files and then copy them to a backup location as below:

```
gci $src `
    | ?{!$_.psiscontainer -and $_.extension.length -eq 0 -and $_ -match "tmp_\d{1}$"} `
    | %{ ren -path $_.fullname -new ($_.name + ".ext") } `
    | %{ cpi -path $_.fullname -dest $bkup -force}
```

The renaming part is working fine. But the renamed files are not being copied over to the backup location. What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default renamed items will not be pushed back onto the pipeline, use the -PassThru switch to pass them on:

```
gci $src `
    | ?{!$_.psiscontainer -and $_.extension.length -eq 0 -and $_ -match "tmp_\d{1}$"} `
    | %{ ren -path $_.fullname -new ($_.name + ".ext") -PassThru } `
    | %{ cpi -path $_.fullname -dest $bkup -force}
```

Comment: I liked this answer as this was closest to what I wanted to achieve. Thanks zdan.

Answer (score 4):

Rename-Item doesn't return anything so there is nothing to pipe to Copy-Item. You could just put both commands in the for each block together:

```
gci $src `
    | ?{!$_.psiscontainer -and $_.extension.length -eq 0 -and $_ -match "tmp_\d{1}$"} `
    | %{ $renamedPath = $_.FullName + ".ext"; `
         ren -path $_.FullName -new $renamedPath; `
         cpi -path $renamedPath -dest $bkup -force }
```

Answer (score 2):

You accomplish both in one operation with move-item.

```
gci $src 
    | ?{!$_.psiscontainer -and $_.extension.length -eq 0 -and $_ -match "tmp_\d{1}$"} 
    | %{
         $newname = $_.Name + ".ext"
         move-item -path $_.FullName -dest "$bkup\$newname"
         }
```

Comment: Rename and copy is not the same as moving.

Answer (score 1):

One liner:

```
gci $src | ?{!$_.psiscontainer -and !$_.extension -and $_ -match 'tmp_\d$'} | move-item -dest {"$bkup\$($_.Name + '.ext')"}
```

Comment: I liked this but I did not want a `move-item` to accomplish what I wanted to do. Thanks for your answer. Is `-match 'tmp_\d$` equivalent to `-match 'tmp_\d{1}$`?

Comment: move-item is used to rename the object instead of using two other commands for the same task (copy and rename). By the way, you can replace move with copy, it should work as well. 'tmp_\d$' is the same as 'tmp_\d{1}$' as it's matching one digit only.